# SQL Foreign key error --Missing index for FK constraint

Tags: sql

```
CREATE DATABASE Company; 
USE Company; 

CREATE TABLE Employee(
 EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
 EmployeeName CHAR(25), 
 DID INT NOT NULL
 );
 
 CREATE TABLE Department( 
 DepartmentID INT NOT NULL, 
 DpartmentName CHAR(25), 
 FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID) REFERENCES Employee(DID)
 );
```

This is a simple SQL query for creating 2 tables and adding a foreign key,

I made sure to--

1. Have same data type
2. Different names in table.
3. Correct syntax.

But still, I get the error for

```
0   23  16:48:05    CREATE TABLE Department( 
  DepartmentID INT NOT NULL, 
  DpartmentName CHAR(25), 
  FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID) REFERENCES Employee(DID)
  ) Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'department_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'employee' 0.329 sec
```

How do I correct this? Thanks in advance

Comment: [[tag:MySQL]] and [[tag:sql-server]] are completely different products. What one are you *really* using?

Comment: MYSQL is the application @Larnu

Comment: As for the error, it's pretty clear, your table `Employee` doesn't have a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE INDEX` on the column `DID`. Though, should the `FOREIGN KEY` be defined in the table `Employee` not `Department`? Surely you can have multiple employees in a department. Or is each department made up of just 1 employee and only ever 1 employee (and if an employee leaves, their department is dissolved)?

Comment: Employee table does have PRIMARY KEY. Do you think, I should make the 'DepartmentID' in 'Department' table the primary key?

Comment: Your reference is to the DID column, which doesn't have an associated index.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get at all these terms. Could you please tell me what I exactly need to do? @JonArmstrong

Comment: Simple: This `FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID) REFERENCES Employee(DID)` makes ZERO sence, stop and think about it

Comment: Check out this fiddle, with your tables.  It shows the error and how I corrected it.  Even though the extra index does correct the problem, **you might want to ask another question about how to change the design**.  Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec0dd4935b67cac7ea3b546453c58211

Comment: As I implied, @KirtiPurohit, you're effectively saying a department belongs to an Employee. So a Employee belong to one department or more departments but a department can only **ever** have one employee. I don't think any business I've worked at, or with, works like that.

Comment: Ohh yes! It worked! Thanks it made sense to me now. Thank you so much

Comment: @KirtiPurohit Did you change the design?  If not, you still have a more serious problem.

Comment: Ohh.. What? I improved upon the issue..what is the serious issue I didn't notice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Missing index for constraint 'department_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'employee'

You need an index on the `DID` column of the `Employee` table if you are creating a foreign key referencing the `Employee.DID` column.

**But** as suggested in the comments, you likely want it the other way around: the `Employee.DID` column sounds like a reference to `Department.Id`.

Thus, the foreign key should be on the `Employee` table, referencing the `Department` table. (And this way, there wouldn't be any error as `Department.id` is already indexed).